# Mouse and keyboard not working (extreme lag) after fresh install Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, grub, mouse

After installing Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.1 (32 bit) on my vaio z laptop, the mouse and keyboard start working for a few seconds, then freeze and continue to work very intermittently. For example, I hit the superkey and at some point within the next 10mins the menu will appear--so like an extreme lag. How may I remedy this?

Please point me in any direction. Both mouse and keyboard work fine on the liveUSB and work in BIOS. `lsusb' returns

```
mint@mint ~ $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 054c:0243 Sony Corp. MicroVault Flash Drive
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0489:e00f Foxconn / Hon Hai Foxconn T77H114 BCM2070 [Single-Chip Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR Adapter]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05c6:9224 Qualcomm, Inc. Sony Gobi 2000 Wireless Modem (QDL mode)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ca:18b7 Ricoh Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:1001 Upek TCS5B Fingerprint sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And `top` returns

```
mint@mint ~ $ top

top - 17:46:09 up 11 min,  8 users,  load average: 0.18, 0.15, 0.14
Tasks: 157 total,   1 running, 156 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.1 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.8 id,  1.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   5864844 total,  1376728 used,  4488116 free,   163672 buffers
KiB Swap:  5951484 total,        0 used,  5951484 free.   807912 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND    
 2247 root      20   0  144232  53528  45516 S   4.3  0.9   0:15.84 Xorg       
 3020 mint      20   0  199240  15876  11784 S   4.3  0.3   0:00.97 gnome-ter+ 
 3321 mint      20   0    5432   1376   1000 R   4.3  0.0   0:00.36 top        
    1 root      20   0    4468   2576   1464 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.88 init       
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd   
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.09 ksoftirqd+ 
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0+ 
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.31 rcu_sched  
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh     
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.54 migration+ 
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 watchdog/0 
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1 
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.51 migration+ 
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.07 ksoftirqd+ 
   15 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1+ 
   16 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.48 watchdog/2 
   17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.08 migration+ 
mint@mint ~ $
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of `lsusb` from a liveCD?

Comment: can you get to a tty? Might be able to do something from there. ctrl-alt-f[1-6]

Comment: I've updated with `lsusb` and `top` from liveUSB. I've not tried a terminal (tty) session yet. Sorry for delayed response I had to go out.

Comment: I cannot get a terminal (tty) session. Nor does the linux reboot `ctrl`+`R` `E` `I` `S` `U` `B` work, i hard restart each time.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate any further comments. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried reinstalling from the liveusb but after the install finishes fine I still get the same problem. The mouse adn keyboard work ok for about 10seconds then stop. I have also tried installed ubuntu 14.04 but the mouse does not work on the flashcd with ubuntu--it is fine with mint.